# Why isn't the "object" parent class for new-style classes in Python2.x written as "Object"?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, object, styles

Maybe I have the wrong impression, but wouldn't the parent class of a `class` object be a class?
If so, why didn't the authors of Python follow good style convention and capitalize the `object` class to `Object` to denote it as a class object? [Is it a class at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375621/881224)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It follows the convention of built-in types (`str`, `int`, `float`, `complex`, `file`, `type`, etc.) *not* having the initial letter capitalized.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Not all objects are created equal.