# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getSA_H'

Tags: python

I'm getting this error. I already tried everything - would be great if someone can help me.

```
class getdata_hauptfach:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Schulaufgabe_Hauptfach = 0.0
        self.EX1_Hauptfach = 0.0
        self.EX2_Hauptfach = 0.0
        self.Muendliche_Note_Hauptfach = 0.0
        self.Kurzarbeit_Hauptfach = 0.0

    def getSA_H(self):
        self.Schulaufgabe_Hauptfach = float(input("Schulaufgabe im Hauptfach:"))

    def getEX1_H(self):
        self.EX1_Hauptfach = float(input("Erste Ex im Hauptfach:"))

    def getEX2_H(self):
        self.EX2_Hauptfach = float(input("Zweite Ex im Hauptfach:"))

    def getM_H(self):
        self.Muendliche_Note_Hauptfach = float(input("Mündliche Note im Hauptfach:"))

    def getK_H(self):
        self.Kurzarbeit_Hauptfach = float(input("Kurzarbeit im Hauptfach:"))

    def getData_H(self):
        count_H = 0
        while count_H <= 5:
            count_H = count_H + 1
            Notenart_H = input('Welche Note möchtest du für das Hauptfach eintragen?')
            if Notenart_H == 'Schulaufgabe':
                self.getSA_H()

            elif Notenart_H == 'Erste Ex':
                self.getEX1_H()

            elif Notenart_H == 'Zweite Ex':
                self.getEX2_H()

            elif Notenart_H == 'Mündliche Note':
                self.getM_H()

            elif Notenart_H == 'Kurzarbeit':
                self.getK_H()

import _sqlite3

from GETDATA_von_Fächer import getdata_hauptfach
from GETDATA_von_Fächer import getdata_nebenfach

conn = _sqlite3.connect('Notenberechnung.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()


class Halbjahre:
    def __init__(self, Halbjahr):
        self.Halbjahr = Halbjahr

    def Abfrage(self):
        self.Halbjahr = input('Welches Halbjahr?')
        self.Fachart = input('Hauptfach oder Nebenfach?')
        self.Fachname = input('Welches Fach?')

    def Speichern_in_Datenbanken(self):
        if self.Halbjahr == '1':
            if self.Fachart == 'Hauptfach':
                getdata_hauptfach.getData_H(self.Halbjahr)

            elif self.Fachart == 'Nebenfach':
                getdata_nebenfach()
                cur.execute()

        elif self.Halbjahr == 2:
            if self.Fachart == 'Hauptfach':
                getdata_hauptfach()
                cur.execute()
            elif self.Fachart == 'Nebenfach':
                getdata_nebenfach()
                cur.execute()



    def Test_finish(self):
        self.Abfrage()
        self.Speichern_in_Datenbanken()

test_Halbjahre = Halbjahre(1)
print(test_Halbjahre.Test_finish())

conn.close()
```

Hopefully someone can help. My friends and me don`t understand why its not working.

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/user/github/Jahresnote/Erste_Abfrage.py", line 59, in <module>
        print(test_Halbjahre.Test_finish())
      File "/Users/user/github/Jahresnote/Erste_Abfrage.py", line 56, in                     Test_finish
        self.Speichern_in_Datenbanken()
      File "/Users/user/github/Jahresnote/Erste_Abfrage.py", line 22, in     Speichern_in_Datenbanken
        getdata_hauptfach.getData_H(self.Halbjahr)
      File "/Users/user/github/Jahresnote/GETDATA_von_Fächer.py", line 31, in getData_H
        self.getSA_H()
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getSA_H'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have reformatted the error message at the end of the page to help read it. I also noticed and fixed an indentation error in `def getSA_H(self)`, where the body was not indented as it should have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code and it might make a difference to pass `object` to the classes, so instead of:

```py
class getdata_hauptfach:
 ...

class Halbjahre:
 ...
```

try:

```py
class getdata_hauptfach(object):
 ...

class Halbjahre(object):
 ...
```

This way you can access all variables and methods passed to that class. You might also want to change the following line:

```py
getdata_hauptfach.getData_H(self.Halbjahr)
```

to

```py
getdata_hauptfach().getData_H(self.Halbjahr)
```

so your class is initialized, and `self` applies to the current class attribute.

You can find some more information on using objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375595/class-with-object-as-a-parameter) or about accessing classes properties in the [docs](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#property)

One simple example of this situation below:

```py
## original way
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one_value = 1
    def get_value(self):
        print (self.one_value)

test.get_value() 
# TypeError: get_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

## correct way
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.one_value = 1
    def get_value(self):
        print (self.one_value)

test().get_value()
# 1
```

Comment: great it worked - but instead of getdata_hauptfach().getData_H(self.Halbjahr) I changed it to getdata_hauptfach().getData_H() - big thank you really appreciate your quick answer - have a great weekend

Comment: Anytime @Felix! Would you mind accepting as the answer if it worked?

Comment: No problem sorry just forgot it